# ARML: Tangent congruent circles forming a right circular cone

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Four congruent circles are tangent to each other and tangent to the
>   edges of a sector as shown. If the straight edges are joined to form a
>   right circular cone with the vertex at P, the radius of the base would
>   be 2/3 the slant height of the cone. Compute the ratio of the radius
>   of the sector to the radius of each circle.

Here's a drawing:

Sorry for the poor artwork. Assume that all four of the small circles are tangent to each other. Assume that everything that seems tangent is tangent.

[image]

I'm thinking about using angle/360 = radius/slant or maybe area of sector = pi * r * l

Hints or solutions are both appreciated, thank you!

Comment: 4 circles are identical, if you connect P and three tangent points, you divide you cone into 4 identical parts. You just deal with one of them

Comment: But since it involves the sector, so don't we have to look at the whole thing?

Comment: Clarification : The radius of the sector is the same as the slant height of the cone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion of the cone convinces me that each of the four sectors containing a single circle will have central angle at $P$ of $\frac{\pi}{3}$

For one sector, the angle bisector at $P$ cut the sector into 2 conguent sectors, each with central angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$  and will pass through the centre of the circle.

Let $x$ represent the radius of the circle , $y$ the distance from $P$ to the centre of the circle and $r$ the slant height of the cone.

clearly $$x+y=r$$

Construct a radius that meets one of the straight sides at the point of tangency. You will have constructed a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $y$ and one side of length $x$ opposite to the central angle of $\frac{\pi}{6}$

so $$ \sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac xy \Rightarrow y=2x $$

putting the two equations together gives $x=\frac r3$

Comment: The slant height of the cone is the radius of the sector. With the vertex angles of the four small triangles at $\frac\pi 3$, the base angle of the cone is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and the radius of the base is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ times the slant height of the cone. This is not the same as $\frac23$.

Comment: I don't agree that the base angle of the cone is $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ I think it should be $ \sin^{-1}(\frac 23)$ , or maybe double that, depending on your definition of base angle.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality for theanswer, we can take the slant height (which is the radius of the sector as well) to be $1$.

Step 0: Let $A$ be the intersection of the sector circumference with the line $PA$ on the let; let $BB$ be the corresponding point on the right. Since the cone is a right circular cone, $\overline{AB}$ is a diameter of the base of the cone so the radius of the cone will then be $\frac12 \overline{AB}$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$; $\overline{AM}$ is a radius of the cone:  $\overline{AM}=\frac{2}{3}$. But if angle $APB = 2\phi$, in triangle $AMP$ we see that 
$$ \phi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac23\right)$$

Step 1: Each of the small circles are in a triangular wedge of radius $1$ with central angle $2\theta$. 
Since for of these angles, plus the $2\phi$ in angle $APB$ gives a full circle,
$$
\phi + 4 \theta = \pi$$
Step 2:  Within that wedge of radius $r=1$ and angle $2\theta$, is inscribed a smaller circle, of radius $s$.  (We wish to find $\frac{1}{s}$ which is the answer required.) What is $s$ in terms of $\theta$?

Label the corners of the wedge $XPY$ where $P$ is the same $P$ as in the main diagram.  Inscribe the circle, and label the center of the circle $O$.  Let the tangent intersection points of circle $O$ with sides $PX$ and and $PY$ be $U$ and $V$ respectively. And let $PO$ meat circle $P$ at $N$.

Angle $PUO$ is a right angle because the circle is tangent to the line. In right triangle $PUO$, side $\overline{OU} = s$ and side $\overline{OP} = s\csc \theta$.
Since $\overline{PN} = 1$ (the radius of circle $P$),
$$
s + s\csc\theta = 1 \implies 
\frac{1}{s} = 1 + \csc \theta
$$
Step 3: We can find $\sin (4\theta)$ easily enough:

$$
4\theta =  \pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac23\right)
\\ \sin(4\theta) = \frac23
$$
and we have to remember later that $4\theta$ is in the second quadrant, so $$\cos(4\theta) = -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{9}$$

Step 4: We now work with half-angle formulas:
$$\cos (2\theta) = \sqrt{\frac12(1+\cos(4\theta))} = \sqrt{\frac12\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{9}\right)} $$
$$
\sin\theta = \sqrt{\frac12(1-\cos(2\theta))} =
\sqrt{\frac12\left(1-\sqrt{\frac12\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{9}\right)}\right)}
$$

Step 5: Now we must take the reciprocal of $\sin \theta$, add $1$ and simplify. The answer comes out numerically to about 4.8766.